# Remove a class from RSS feed in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

If someone can help to remove a class from my RSS feed in WordPress, completely I want to remove below code from my RSS feed.

`<div class="well"> <a class="btn" href="foo.com">foo</a></div>`

If noticed well, there could be done via function. If you know the trick please share your solution.

Thanks in advance,
Gregory

Comment: @ceejayoz cheers for the explanation mate. I have correct describe my question above.

Comment: You're welcome! I flagged the comment for deletion; your original question was fine, and you may want to revert to it as the answer may be different with the [shortcode] format versus the <div> format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'remove_sc_rss_feed');

function remove_sc_rss_feed( $content )
{
    global $post;

    // Remove div with class using regex
    $content = preg_replace('#<div class="well">(.*?)</div>#', '', $post->post_content);

    return $content;
}
```

Note: You might not see the changes immediately. Wordpress RSS feeds cache for a few hours. I'd suggest installing a caching plugin and not cache the feed. I think this plugin will do it https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Comment: That is from the shortcode @veggera? The shortcode has class `well`.

Comment: See updates @veggera. I haven't tested it but should work. I'd suggest using JS/Jquery to remove the div and class on the frontend as it's the DOM elements.

Comment: I have tested purge also the RSS feed from cache but the div class are still in RSS feed.

Comment: @veggera please try test with test content updates to see if your purge of the cache is working. I haven’t tested this, I’ll try test it out and post my findings here